# Enviar dato mediante ajax a input

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, huelladigital

Tengo que enviar un dato a mi formulario mediante ajax, esto lo hace correctamente.

```
    function cargar_push() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "Model/httpush.php",
        data: "&timestamp=" + timestamp,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

            timestamp = json["timestamp"];
            imageHuella = json["imgHuella"];
            tipo = json["tipo"];
            id = json["id"];
            $("#" + id + "_status").text(json["statusPlantilla"]);
            $("#" + id + "_texto").text(json["texto"]);
            if (imageHuella !== null) {
                $("#" + id).attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + imageHuella);
                if (tipo === "leer") {
                $("#NoEmp").val(json["NoEmp"]);
                //checar();
                }
            }
        setTimeout("cargar_push()", 500);
        }
    });
}
```

posteriormente tengo el archivo donde recibo el dato

```
<input name="NoEmp" id="NoEmp"  class="form-control especial negrita-gris" type="number" placeholder="# Empleado"  onChange="checar()" title="Oprima enter para checar su entrada">
```

todo bien hasta acá, el problema se me presenta al querer usar la función checar() con el evento onChange

```
<script type="text/javascript">
cargar_push();

function checar()
{
    document.getElementById('mov').value='RegistroNvo';
    document.getElementById('frm').submit();
}
document.getElementById('NoEmp').value='';
document.getElementById('NoEmp').focus();
```

sí recibo el dato y cambian los valores según el cambio huella, pero el input queda inhabilitado (he estado buscando y al parecer podría ser un detalle con el setTimeOut).

Como comentario estoy trabajando en un sistema de checado con un lector de huellas digitapersona 4500, usando java.

Espero alguien me pueda orientar si existe alguna forma de hacer que funcione.

Mi objetivo es que cuando detecte una huella diferente automaticamente se haga lance checar().

Como anotación: dejé comentado en cargar_push() la funcion checar(), ya que ahí si lo hace pero como tiene el setTimeOut cada 500 milisegundos hace peticiones a la base de datos y mi hosting me lo detecta como ataque.

Comment: ¿Tu problema es que nunca se ejecuta `checar()` porque el evento `onchange` no se dispara cuando la llamada asincrona se completa y guardas contenido en el input, correcto?
¿Que problema hay con llamar a la función dentro de la llamada asíncrona?
Si no quieres hacerlo así, prueba con un MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Si, no se ejecuta.
Si lo llamo desde ajax, se ejecuta cada 500 milisegundos y mi hosting me detecta como ataque, bloqueando la ip del cliente.
Leeré el link que me mandaste, muchas gracias.